# Breaking change for google-api-python-client 1.8.1 - AttributeError: module 'googleapiclient' has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

After upgrading to the new `google-api-python-client` 1.8.1 I'm receiving this error. Do we know if python 3.8 breaks the latest `google-api-core`? And whether there's a solution

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
     worker.init_process()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
     self.load_wsgi()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
     self.callable = self.load()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
     return self.load_wsgiapp()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
     __import__(module)
   File "/prosebit/prosebit/app.py", line 10, in <module>
     from prosebit.blueprints.page import page
   File "/prosebit/prosebit/blueprints/page/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
     from prosebit.blueprints.page.views import page
   File "/prosebit/prosebit/blueprints/page/views.py", line 4, in <module>
     from prosebit.blueprints.page.gmail import get_google_auth, ListHistory, add_to_watch, 
     is_meter_data, ListMessagesMatchingQuery, GetMessage, send_message, get_daily_threadid, 
     ModifyMessage, create
     MsgLabels, get_new_messages
  File "/prosebit/prosebit/blueprints/page/gmail.py", line 32, in <module>
     from apiclient import errors
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apiclient/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
     __version__ = googleapiclient.__version__
 AttributeError: module 'googleapiclient' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
Successfully installed Blinker-1.4 Click-6.4 Flask-1.1.1 Flask-Login-0.4.1 Flask-Mail-0.9.1 Flask-
SQLAlchemy-2.4.1 Flask-WTF-0.14.3 Jinja2-2.11.2 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 SQLAlchemy-1.3.7 SQLAlchemy-Utils-0.36.3 WTForms-2.
2.1 WTForms-Alchemy-0.16.9 WTForms-Components-0.10.4 amqp-2.5.2 atomicwrites-1.3.0 attrs-19.3.0 billiard-3.6.3.0 cachetools-4.1.0 celery-4.4.0 certifi-2020.4.5.1 chardet-3.0.4 coverage-5.1 decorator-4.4.2 entrypoin
ts-0.3 faker-3.0.0 flake8-3.7.8 flask-debugtoolbar-0.10.1 gocardless-pro-1.10.0 google-api-core-1.16.0 google-api-python-client-1.8.1 google-auth-1.14.0 google-auth-httplib2-0.0.3 google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.1 google-
cloud-pubsub-1.4.3 googleapis-common-protos-1.51.0 grpc-google-iam-v1-0.12.3 grpcio-1.28.1 gunicorn-19.9.0 httplib2-0.17.2 idna-2.9 infinity-1.4 intervals-0.8.1 itsdangerous-1.1.0 kombu-4.6.8 mccabe-0.6.1 mock-3.0.
5 more-itertools-8.2.0 oauth2client-4.1.3 oauthlib-3.1.0 packaging-20.3 pluggy-0.13.1 protobuf-3.11.3 psycopg2-2.8.4 py-1.8.1 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 pycodestyle-2.5.0 pyflakes-2.1.1 pyparsing-2.4.7 pytes
t-5.1.0 pytest-cov-2.7.1 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2019.3 redis-3.3.11 requests-2.23.0 requests-oauthlib-1.3.0 rsa-4.0 six-1.14.0 stripe-2.41.0 text-unidecode-1.3 uritemplate-3.0.1 urllib3-1.25.9 validators-0.14.3
 vine-1.3.0 wcwidth-0.1.9 werkzeug-1.0.0
```

Comment: looks like a known issue --> https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/870#issuecomment-616861057 and the comment says to import from `googleapiclient`

Comment: For those who hit this issue with PyDrive lib - here is the discussion: https://github.com/gsuitedevs/PyDrive/issues/196 TL;DR; - use PyDrive2 that is actively maintained fork.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same error and changing the import fixed it for me. The developers recommend [importing from `googleapiclient` instead of `apiclient`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/870#issuecomment-616861057).

So you will need to change `from apiclient import errors` to `from googleapiclient import errors`