# download files from google drive via python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

After searching in this site, I found that pydrive allows one to download files from google drive.

But when I try this:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
```

I get a AttributeError:

```
 module googleapiclient has no attribute '__version__'
```

and i see where the error is:

```
__version__ = googleapiclient.__version__
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: Possibly duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61334085/breaking-change-for-google-api-python-client-1-8-1-attributeerror-module-goo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Breaking change for google-api-python-client 1.8.1 - AttributeError: module 'googleapiclient' has no attribute '\_\_version\_\_'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61334085/breaking-change-for-google-api-python-client-1-8-1-attributeerror-module-goo)